# Get method Validation in postman

Tags: postman

Can anyone help me on how to validate BONUSBALANCE in the below [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9twm.png)?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `xml2Json` lib correctly, however, your path to `BONUSBALANCE` parameter is slightly imprecise. Try this:

```
const jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
pm.test('Assert Bonus Balance', () => pm.expect(jsonObject.RSP.BONUSBALANCE).to.equal('100.00000'));
```